# Asymptotic distribution of MLE of iid exponentials?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, iid

If $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ are iid exponentially distributed with mean $\zeta$ then the Fisher information is $n/\zeta^2$, the MLE estimator is $\sum Y_i /n$, and the variance of $Y_i$ is $\zeta^2$.

By a theorem of Cramër, the MLE is asymptotically normal with mean $\zeta$ and variance equal to $1/n$ times the inverse Fisher information, that is $\zeta^2 /n^2$.

Yet by CLT, the MLE is asymptotically normal with mean $\zeta$ and variance equal to $1/n$ times the variance of $X_i$, that is $\zeta^2/n$.

Which one is it? Why don't they agree? Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the Fisher information in this case (as defined in the Wikipedia article) is $\frac{n}{\zeta^2}$. This can be derived easily enough.

From the CLT we have that $\frac{\bar Y_n - \zeta}{SE(\bar Y_n)} \rightarrow_d \mathcal N(0,1)$.

$Var(\bar Y_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n Var(Y_i) = \zeta^2/n$ (although we could have just used $I^{-1}(\zeta)$ instead) so
$$
\bar Y_n \rightarrow_d \mathcal N(\zeta, \zeta^2/n).
$$

As for the Cramer theorem, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify which theorem you are referring to?

If you are referring to the [Cramer-Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound), this tells us that $Var(\hat \zeta) \geq I^{-1}(\zeta) = \frac{\zeta^2}{n}$. This is the same variance in the CLT so there is no disagreement here; indeed, this says that asymptotically we are doing as well as we can.

$$
\
$$

$$
\
$$

Here's the derivation that $I(\zeta) = \frac{n}{\zeta^2}$. By $Y_i$ iid we have
$$
L(\zeta ; \vec Y) = \prod_i \frac{1}{\zeta} \exp (\frac{-Y_i}{\zeta}) = {1 \over \zeta^n} \exp (-\frac{1}{\zeta} \sum_i Y_i)
$$

$$
\implies l(\zeta; \vec Y) := \log L(\zeta; \vec Y) = -\frac{1}{\zeta} \sum_i Y_i - n \log \zeta.
$$

Taking two derivatives we find that 
$$
l''(\zeta; \vec Y) = \frac{-2 \sum_i Y_i}{\zeta^3} + \frac{n}{\zeta^2}
$$

and therefore
$$
I(\zeta) = \mathbb E_Y(-l''(\zeta; \vec Y)) = \frac{n}{\zeta^2}.
$$

Comment: The theorem by Cramér is a theorem in our professor's own textbook. I cannot find the result online, and am now strongly convinced that it must be a mistake. I ran a simulation, and it doesn't show up either (it's the CLT result that is the correct one).

Comment: The CLT result definitely is true for the iid case that we are considering. It does seem likely that this was a typo. Was the theorem perhaps the Cramer-Rao bound that I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: (+1) Another possibility is that in reading the statement of the theorem, the *probability density* might have been confused with the *likelihood*.  (This confusion seems to be happening in the other reply.)

Comment: No, it was another one.

Comment: The expression $\bar{Y} \to_d N(\zeta, \zeta^2/n)$ is not a correct math expression. Besides, as I pointed out in my answer, the rigorous definition of Fisher information should not depend on sample size $n$.

Comment: @Solitary Your definition (which clearly views the random variable as *univariate* in your answer) is too limited, because it could then only be useful for likelihoods arising in IID circumstances.  I cannot find any textbook on my shelves that is so restrictive.

Comment: I acknowledge that depending on different context, the term "Fisher information" can have different definitions. But, for the one appeared in Cramer's theorem, I am pretty sure it doesn't depend on $n$. See the comment I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Fisher information, defined as 
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{[f'(u)]^2}{f(u)} du,$$
is independent of the sample size $n$. I didn't include any parameter $\theta$ here since the above definition applies to more general setting such as nonparametric inference.

---

For your case, based on your description, $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ i.i.d. $\sim \text{Exp}(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a scale parameter, thus the density of $Y_1$ is
$$f_Y(y; \zeta) = \frac{1}{\zeta}e^{-y/\zeta}, y > 0.$$
Hence by definition (once again, the standard definition of Fisher information doesn't depend on sample), the Fisher information is 
$$I(\zeta) = \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\zeta^3} - \frac{2y}{\zeta^4} + \frac{y^2}{\zeta^5}\right) e^{-y/\zeta}dy = \frac{1}{\zeta^2}$$
Since $\bar{Y} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ is MLE, based on MLE asymptotic theory (may correspond to your "Cramer theorem"), we have
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y} - \zeta) \Rightarrow N(0, I(\zeta)^{-1}) = N(0, \zeta^2).$$

On the other hand, since $\text{Var}(Y_1) = \zeta^2$, it follows by classical CLT that
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y} - \zeta) \Rightarrow N(0, \zeta^2).$$
So these two results agree very well.

In fact, Cramer's theorem is deduced from CLT (under some regularity conditions), so logically they are bounded to give the identical limiting distributions.

Comment: What? The Fisher information was defined, to me, as the expectation of the observed information function. This expectation equals $n/\zeta^2$.

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) wiki link.

Comment: I'd like a different answer since yours is not making any sense to me.

Comment: Did you read the wiki page? At least you can get from there the definition of Fisher information doesn't depend on a particular sample, but only depends on the underlying true population.

Comment: Then how does this explain that the Fisher information of a series of iid exponentials does depend on $n$?

Comment: I will add more details.

Comment: When you do add them, please be clear about what you understand $f$ to be. In the Wikipedia article you reference, it's the *likelihood*, which implicitly depends (heavily) on $n$. There's no apparent reason for that dependence to disappear in the integral.

Comment: @whuber The Fisher information appeared in Cramer's theorem (for a possible reference, see Theorem 18 from Ferguson's _A Course in Large Sample Theory_) doesn't depend on $n$, it is defined for a single random variable $X$. The $f$ then refers to the density of that random variable $X$.

Comment: I am glad you have edited your answer to clarify what $f$ is.  Note, though, that it disagrees with the definition in the Wikipedia article you referenced in a comment, where $f$ refers to the likelihood.  I suspect this difference in possible definitions might explain the inconsistency observed in the question. (+1)

Comment: The wiki link I gave, at the very beginning, actually also defines Fisher information as the expectation with respect to a single random variable. Somehow it becomes confusing later because it says something related to additivity of Fisher information. Yes, I understand that this term has two seemingly all reasonable, but quite different definitions. It might bring us inconvenience in communication. Do you think it's necessary for me to provide the definition and the theorem given in Ferguson's book?

Comment: The wikipedia article cannot be properly understood unless that "single random variable" is taken as vector-valued. Otherwise, much of the portion that follows "Information is additive ..." refers to quantities that have no definition. The appearance of $n$ in subsequent examples reinforces this interpretation. I don't think you necessarily need to reproduce the material in Ferguson's book, but referencing it explicitly would give your answer a little more authority.